# Does the System.Diagnostics.EventLog class participate in transactions when calling the WriteEntry method?

Tags: .net, event-log

I'm making calls in a transaction, and when an exception is thrown (thus preventing my scope.complete()) I don't see them, even though I know they were called.

[Edit: For clarification - this is running on Server 2008 R2, .Net 3.5]

[Edit: added example - basically answers the question, but if someone could cite documentation somewhere]

```
EventLog.WriteEntry("Start.");

using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope()) {

EventLog.WriteEntry("Middle.");

throw new applicationexception("Whatever");

scope.Complete();

}

EventLog.WriteEntry("End.");
```

My event log shows only Start and End.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EventLog does not support transactions.  I don't think there is any specific documentation on this. Which makes sense since the documentation rarely mentions things that are **not** supported unless there is some explicit reason to do so (clarifications, common misconception, etc.).

From a practical point of view a simple test shows that messages are logged even if the transaction is rolled back:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry("Application", "Start");

        using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry("Application", "123");
        }

        EventLog.WriteEntry("Application", "End");
    }
}
```

In the event viewer I see 3 events ("Start", "123", "End").

From a theoretical point of view the `EventLog` would need to have a [resource manager to participate in the transaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229975%28VS.80%29.aspx).  Either `EventLog` would need to implement [`IEnlistmentNotification`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.ienlistmentnotification.aspx) or contain a class that implements [`IEnlistmentNotification`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.ienlistmentnotification.aspx).  An inspection of `EventLog` in reflector shows that it doesn't implement [`IEnlistmentNotification`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.ienlistmentnotification.aspx).